# How can I get values from two observables sequentially?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm a newbie with RxJs.

My purpose is : (1) make a first call backend and get value, then (2) based on the returned value, make an other call backend and return both values as an array.

When I subscribe, I would like get both values : building and buildingUnit.

This is the way of I trying to achieve this purpose :

```
this._buildingsService.loadBuilding(1).pipe(
  mergeMap((b: Building) => {
    if (b) {
      return this._buildingUnitsService.loadBuildingUnit(b);
    }
  })
).subscribe((bu: BuildingUnit) => {

});
```

The kind of result that I would like to get back :

```
this._buildingsService.loadBuilding(1).pipe(
  mergeMap((b: Building) => {
    if (b) {
      return this._buildingUnitsService.loadBuildingUnit(b);
    }
  })
).subscribe((b: Building, bu: BuildingUnit) => {

});
```

Thank you

Comment: This can be done using `resultSelector` argument for operators such as `mergeMap`. Otherwise following the [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-result-selector-migration) use a `map` operator on the inner observable to create an object or array containing the properties you need to be in the subscribe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just map the second value into an array.

```
this._buildingsService.loadBuilding(1).pipe(
  mergeMap((b: Building) => {
    if (b) {
      return this._buildingUnitsService.loadBuildingUnit(b).pipe(
        map(c => [b, c]),
      );
    }
    return of([b]); // or `[b, undefined]` to be more obvious
  })
  .subscribe(([b, c]) => {
    // ...
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `forkJoin` to pass both values back:

```js
this._buildingsService.loadBuilding(1).pipe(
  mergeMap((b: Building) => forkJoin({
    b: of(b),
    bu: b ? this._buildingUnitsService.loadBuildingUnit(b) : of(null)
  }))
).subscribe((result: { b: Building, bu: BuildingUnit  }) => {

});
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p5vtej